# Optically reduce chromatic aberration - is it worth trying?

Tags: macro, sharpness, extension-tubes, chromatic-aberration

I have been using this [Tamron SP 180mm 1:1 Macro - F/32](http://www.tamron-usa.com/product/lenses/b01.html) lens to digitize 35mm slides. Unfortunately, the lens' chromatic aberration is quite noticeable, when used at 1:1.

I have plenty of strobe light available and have been shooting at F/16, 2 stops from a completely closed (F/32) aperture, to obtain a the best combination of sharpness and depth of field.

I was thinking that I might be able to reduce some of that aberration optically -- by blocking off the portion of the light that is entering the lens' section that is most likely to produce the chromatic aberration.

This image illustrates what I am tempting to put in front of the lens. (And maybe without the center part, based on the comments...)

[image: to block off light that is likely to cause chromatic aberration]

Now having this in front of the lens I'm guessing I'll probably have to open up to F/8, or even more to obtain an image without a visual effect of the new lens-cap/obstruction.

Note, I also have a 12mm; a 20mm; and a 36mm extension tubes (from Kenko) available -- to see if that, in combination, would help fight the chromatic aberration problem.

I know there are other maybe more appropriate lenses on the market; but I very much depend on the auto-focus aspect of the setup.

One other thing to consider is to use two lenses, both set to infinite; but this causes a working distance problem.

Any suggestions and other thought are very much appreciated.

[image: sample image]

---

### placed "a" in the center:

The "a", if positioned in the center of the image, reveals less chromatic aberration.

[image: a in center of image]

---

### pattern setup:

I printed the pattern out using a laser printer and glued the printout onto some clear plastic that has the size and shape of a slide. For the light source: I used the same as for the slides -- backlit soft strobe light. It looks based on the f/3.5 shot, that the camera sensor is not completely parallel to the paper.

[image: f3.5]

---

[image: f16]

---

[image: f32]

---

### Blocking off light test

Reducing from 60mm diameter to 40mm diameter. It looks like it is a bit sharper, but do not see an improvement in the CA department.

[image: blocking off]

Comment: Why so dependent on the AF aspect - working speed, or lack of a live view capable camera? Imprecise AF sounds like a major source of apparent CA here (spherochromatism etc...) ....

Comment: Also, you don't need large DoF when your entire subject is in one flat plane. You're better off selecting the aperture that gives the best optical performance from your lens.

Comment: @rackandboneman The AF aspect helps, as each slide varies. And some are not flat. [CA?](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CA)

Comment: @rackandboneman spherochromatism ... so stay away using a extension tube.

Comment: Nothing to do with extension tubes - some lenses have much more CA when they are ALMOST in focus. For slide copying, manual focus at working aperture with magnified live view is probably the most precise option.

Comment: AF won't help you with non-flat slides :) DoF would, that's why I would suggest you use a shorter macro lens here anyway - I like the Leitz R 60mm/2.8 on an APS-C camera for slide copying. Will still cost less than a 6x6 slide scanner even if you include a small pre owned 16MP DSLM and adapter. ... there were special projection lenses for glassless slides, maybe adapting such a lens could help with the non-flatness problems...

Comment: Even if it works as you think, the additional edges will add a lot of diffraction, so your result might look 'color-corrected but unsharp'. Why not correct the Chromatic Aberration in post-processing?

Comment: @MeSo2 Can you add a photo that shows what you think is chromatic aberration?  Usually CA is significantly reduced just by closing the aperture 1-2 stops.  If you're still seeing artifacts at F16, they may not be CA.

Comment: Why do you think blocking the center of the lens would help CA?  If anything, I'd expect it to worsen CA.

Comment: @xiota sounds like a colossal misunderstanding of what makes catoptric lenses CA-free :)

Comment: How can you tell that the CA is from your lens and not already present in the picture (old lenses were not CA-free...)?

Comment: @xiota 'Why do you think blocking the center of the lens would help CA?' I remember that when designing lenses that it is the extremities that need to be eliminated - so the outside and just as much the center.

Comment: The "extremities" do *not* include the center.  Consider on a human.  Extremities refer to the arms and legs, *not* the heart and lungs.

Comment: @xenoid 'How can you tell that the CA is from your lens...' good point! I found that the amount of CA looks about the same across different slides that where shot with different lenses.

Comment: @xiota _The "extremities" do not include the center._ Sorry, I had to rethink that ... yes, you are right for CA, but for reducing [spherical aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration) it would help ... really all depending on the weak spot of the lens when used at a 1:1 position.

Comment: Spherical aberration is also significantly reduced when stopping down the aperture.  I doubt the center has significant involvement.  Do you have an optics text you're referencing?  Good macro lenses should already be well-corrected for aberrations and distortion.  If a cheap hack would help, the manufacturer would have already included it in the lens.  (I have some macro lenses designed for >1:1 that have permanently stopped-down, fixed aperture.)

Comment: @Aganju _Why not correct the Chromatic Aberration in post-processing?_ This is what I have been doing; but I've noticed that (now shooting at 9.5K) some of the grain gets smushed together after the correction, and looks less sharp.

Comment: @MeSo2 Since the letter 'a' at F4 and F16 look identical, the colors along the edges are probably part of the original. Can you photograph some text or pattern that's been printed with a black & white laser printer? Use a tripod and apertures F3.5, F5.6, F8, F11, F16, F22.

Comment: @xiota I added more images, I will now start experimenting with some blocking off the light shots.

Comment: @MeSo2 You skipped F5.6, F8, and F11.  What camera are you using?  F32 looks worse than F16, so it's probably caused by diffraction (different wavelengths bend by different degrees).  The best aperture will probably be F8.

Comment: @xiota sorry for skipping these F stops. It was quite a bit of work to pull these images. I now tried blocking off the light (just the outer part, leaving the center in.) I will add them soon.

Comment: @MeSo2 You're just replicating the function of the aperture at a non-optimal position in the optical pathway.  If the lens is so bad, why don't you try another one?

Comment: @xiota it is the only lens I have for that camera. It clearly has a problem.

Comment: @xiota the camera is a full frame size sensor camera; [Sony a7r iv](https://www.sony.com/electronics/interchangeable-lens-cameras/ilce-7rm4#product_details_default). It is difficult to find a AF lens for that size and working distance; I guess dumping AF is the next option.

Comment: @xiota you got me thinking and I am now considering the Voigtlander MACRO APO-LANTHAR 110mm f/2.5 Lens for Sony-E. This is not what I had in mind starting this post... but it is clear to me that this Tamron lens is not cutting it. Or is there another lens anyone suggests using for this kind of setup? (I have been using the LA-EA adapter with the Tamron lens.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102783/discussion-between-xiota-and-meso2).

Comment: Why the working distance problem - a 50 or 60mm macro lens tends to be perfectly good for digitizing slides, AND will give you far less CA and DoF headaches?

Comment: Also: This 180mm seems like a complex internal focusing lens - prime candidates for IQ trouble in adapted setups.

Comment: @rackandboneman _Why the working distance problem_ I am shooting into a slide projector that _holds_ the slide for me. Also, the lighting is setup for a longer lens. I will be replacing the 180mm. The CA is just too strong.

Comment: I'm no expert in slide copying, but I think something like a Neewer T100 lamp used as a light table works swell :)

Comment: Also... shooting into a slide projector intuitively sounds like shooting into midday sun (which is also great if you want CA problems) ;)

Comment: @rackandboneman the slide projector only _holds_ the slide - I modified the projector by removing the lens (plus some more) and the light. The added new light is a strobe and some white milk glass (opal glass) at 65mm distance to the slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it is not possible.

I swapped out the lens to an [APO macro lens](https://www.voigtlaender.de/lenses/e-mount/110-mm-12-5-macro-apo-lanthar/?lang=en), and now I have a clean CA free image.